# Haskell types and value constructor

Tags: haskell

Reading through a book I came across Haskell Bool Type which is

```
data Bool = True | False
```

As I understand in this case True and False are values and the expression of below type is valid

```
c = True
```

Later on, when I wanted to create a new type I forgot to name the Value constructor and created the following type.

```
data Cartesian2D = Double Double
```

In this case, Haskell (GHCI) did not complain.

But when I tried to construct a value like

```
x = 1.0 2.0
```

and

```
x = Double Double
```

in both cases, Haskell returned an error.

In this case,

1. Is the type Cartesian2D valid?
2. if the type is not valid, why did Haskell not complain when I was constructing the type? but only informed me while constructing a value of the type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data constructors like `True` and type constructors like `Bool` exist in separate namespaces. `True` is an example of a *nullary* constructor, taking no arguments. As such, the definition

```
data Cartesian2D = Double Double
```

defines a type constructor named `Cartesian2D` and a *unary* data constructor named `Double`. Non-nullary data constructors behave much like functions, taking arguments to return a value of their associated type. Here, `Double` behaves like a function of type `Double -> Cartesian2D` (again, note that the type constructor `Double` and the type constructor `Double` are *distinct*).

```
x = Double 1.0
y = Double 2.0
```

To create a "real" Cartesian point type that stores two doubles, try something like

```
data Cartesian2D = Point Double Double
```

which defines a data constructor `Point` that takes two values of type `Double` to create a value of type `Cartesian2D`.

---

If you are at all bothered by the fact that nullary data constructors are somehow "special" in not behaving like functions (i.e., you don't have to call `True`, it just *is* a value), you can think of nullary constructors as being shorthand for unary constructors that take a dummy argument of type `()`:

```
True :: Bool
```

is short for

```
True () :: () -> Bool
```

which would always have to be used as `True ()` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the point here is that when I declared data Cartesian2D = Double Double the first Double is the name of the value constructor instead of the Double type. Why does haskell allow name of value constructor that matches an existing type? This can cause some confusion.

Comment: Also when you mentioned that Bool exists in a separate namespace, what namespace are you talking about?

Comment: (again, note that the type constructor Double and the type constructor Double are distinct). -- this is exactly the sort of confusion I am talking about.

Comment: It's convenient in some cases to reuse the type name as the name of a data constructor for the same type, e.g., `data Point = Point Double Double`. The separate namespaces are what allow you to reuse the name: the language can always tell from context whether any given use of `Point` refers to the type or the data constructor.

Comment: @working When there is only one constructor, it is very common to name the constructor exactly as the type, since it's easier to remember which type has which constructor, and vice versa.

Comment: @chi, I tend to agree but I don't like that there are no restrictions on the name, in this case I was confused because I thought Double was a data type and I came to know that its a valid value constructor name.